# Have anyone use google cloud print in android?

Tags: android, printing

Now we can use google clound print on our application. But I found nothing download in its site which only has a simple document.

What I want to know is where can I download the API and where can I get an android example using google cloud print.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Still the API for Android phone is not availabe. I also checked its website and its giving '404' Error. Instead you can use [Cloud Print App](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.pauloslf.cloudprint&hl=en) and can integrate this app in your android app to print jobs of your interest.

Answer (score 0):

you can find Android example how-to here:

https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/android

It uses WebView, and don't forget to add Internet permisson into manifest, if you don't have it there yet.